# how to calculate gain percentage in java? What is

Tags: java, percentage

I got wrong output while i running this code*****

```
package gain_per;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op,rc,sp,cost,gain;
        double gp=0;

        System.out.println("Enter Old Price:");
        op = sn.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Repair cost:");
        rc = sn.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Selling Price:");
        sp = sn.nextInt();

        if(op != 0 && rc != 0 && sp != 0) {

            cost = op+rc;

            if(cost<sp) {

                gain = sp-cost;
                gp = (float)((gain / cost) * 100);

                System.out.println(gp);

            }
            else {

                System.out.println("Cannot Calculate");
            }

        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }

    }

}
```

**This is my code !!!
What is wrong with this?
The output i get is 0.0**

Comment: for which input, and what output do you expect?

Comment: You are performing an integer division which gives the result 0 since the result is somewhere between 0 and 1. Use double as type for your variables instead. And casting to float afterwards doesn't help since you are casting 0 to 0.0

Comment: Change int gain to float gain.

Answer (score 0):

it because gain is int, cost is also int, gain/cost will return int and if gain less than cost then gain/cost = 0. You need to cast such as: ((float)gain)/cost, to make the expression become float/int which will return float

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing divisions on `int` which will give `zero`. so what you need to do is cast `gain` and `cost` to float first then multiply it with 100.
e.g: `gp = (((float) gain / (float) cost) * 100);`

full code:

```
package gain_per;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int op,rc,sp,cost,gain;
    double gp=0;

    System.out.println("Enter Old Price:");
    op = sn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Repair cost:");
    rc = sn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Selling Price:");
    sp = sn.nextInt();

    if(op != 0 && rc != 0 && sp != 0) {

        cost = op+rc;

        if(cost<sp) {

            gain = sp-cost;
            gp = (((float) gain / (float) cost) * 100);

            System.out.println(gp);

        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Cannot Calculate");
        }

    }
    else {

        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gp=(((float)gain/(float)cost)*100)` and replace `if(op != 0 && rc != 0 && sp != 0)` by `if(op > 0 && rc >= 0 && sp > 0)`.